# "En appelant le numéro suivant"?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, gérondif

**Je suis en train d'aider quelqu'un en lui disant qu'il devrait appeler un numéro sans frais pour obtenir une confirmation.**

Est-ce exact si je dis : vous obtiendrez la confirmation "*en appelant*" ce numéro : XXX-XXX-XXX?

**Aussi, est-ce ça le gérondif ?**

Comment: Tout est correct.

Comment: Et oui le gérondif en français c'est la forme verbale en -ant (participe présent) précédé de la préposition *en*.

Answer (score 5):

Oui, la manière dont vous le dites est correcte.

Voici un [lien](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-83422.php) qui peut vous aider à comprendre le gérondif, mais j'ajoute les explications **directement** tirées du site si le lien devient invalide :

Le gérondif peut être utilisé pour exprimer... :

> a) La simultanéité: *Je mange et je regarde la télévision. Je mange en regardant la télévision.*
>
> b) La condition: *S'il arrive tôt, il pourra assister au concert. En arrivant tôt il pourra assister au concert.*
>
> c) La cause: ***Répond à la question -pourquoi?**. En étant malade elle n'a pu aller au travail.*
>
> d) La manière: ***Répond à la question -comment?**. En feuilletant mes livres j'ai trouvé d' anciennes photographies.*
>
> e) Le temps: ***Répond à la question -quand?**. En sortant de la Faculté j'ai rencontré Juliette.*
>
> f) La concession ou l'opposition: *Quand 'tout' précède le gérondif. Je suis rentré chez moi tout en ignorant qu'ils seraient là.*

J'espère que ces explications vous aideront,

Cordialement