# problem with understanding the use of en

Tags: en

I read this sentence in a book

> Le taxi s'éleva à la verticale. Gaal regardait par la fenêtre incurvée, en se cramponnant instinctivement à la banquette.

However, I dont understand the specific use on en in the second sentence, it doesn't seem to replace anything. Can somebody please explain it to me?

Comment: *En* followed by the present participle of the verb is called a gerund. You will find a question & answer about this [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/20031/358) (it's in French). [This link](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/present-participle/) (in English) could help.

Comment: @None Why not make it an answer? Comments aren't supposed to be used to asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

In French, the construction *en + [participe présent]* is used to mean **while ________ing**. It is called [***le gérondif***](https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/how-to-form-le-gerondif-en-ant-whileby-ing). This is one use of *en*; the use you're thinking of is that of *en* as a pronoun that replaces phrases with de/de la/du. This is not the case here, as you've pointed out.

With this in mind, I (a non-native French speaker) would translate your sentence as

> The taxi rose vertically. Gaal watched through the curved window **while** instinctively **holding on to** the seat.